# Can I use a Comparator class to order a TreeMap in Java 1.6?

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator, treemap, java-6

I have the following problem into a Java 6 application I try to do

```
QuotaTirComparator bvc = new QuotaTirComparator(mappaQuote);
TreeMap<Integer, QuotaTir> sorted_map = new TreeMap<Integer, QuotaTir>(bvc);
```

to obtained a sorted TreeMap.

But Eclipse give me the following error message:

> `The constructor TreeMap<Integer,QuotaTir>(QuotaTirComparator) is undefined`

Why? Is this feature not enabled in Java 6? What is wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: In your TreeMap, the comparator must extend Comparator<Integer> not Comparator<QuotaTir>.  Notice that the constructor for TreeMap is defined as "TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)" where the K is the Key type.  Another way to phrase this is "No, you can't do that".

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that `QuotaTirComparator` is not a `Comparator` Obviously, the Comparator must be for the keys, not the values. As `Integer` already has a natural ordering, I would try removing the comparator altogether.

A Tree is sorted *keys* with associated values.  If you want to sort the `QuoteTir` you need a SortedSet of them.

The Constructor which takes a comparator was adding Java 1.2 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-

Answer (score 1):

Check the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)

The comparator should compare the keys, not values.

Comment: While this was also my initial though based on comparator name and value type name, something tells me that compiler would give different error for that case. So this is probably answer for question which will appear after solving problem pointed by Peter.

Comment: Eclipse gives the same error that he described, except with the parameterized type info in TreeMap.

Comment: OK, what I missed is possibility that OP actually posted error with parameterized types, but since this is browser `<..>` part wasn't shown. I fixed it in the question.